# How do I get the current day of week in C++ using date.h?

Tags: c++, date, c++14, c++-chrono, dayofweek

I am using C++ 14 and am trying to get the current day of week. After some reading I am using [date.h](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) by Howard E. Hinnant.

However I am struggling to get a day of the week (encoded as 0 thru 6).

Something like this prints out `Thu`:

```
 int main(void)
 {
     date::sys_days t;
     weekday wd{t};
     cout << wd << '\n';
 }
```

Many answers on this site regarding getting the current day of the week use `chrono`.

How can I print the current weekday as a range from 0-6 according to when the program is run, using `date.h`?

For example, if I run the program today (Tuesday) I would expect a value of 2.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

---

Just to be clear about what I am trying to achieve, something similar in Java:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));
int dayOfWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

Comment: What's the problem with the program you listed?

Comment: @einpoklum the program I present always prints out `Thu`. I want to be able to print out the current day of the week

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `t` is not being initialized to anything interesting. You just need to set it to "now". There's a slight hitch, though: `now()` returns a different kind of time point, that can't automagically be converted into a `date::sys_days` value.

So, here's the minimal change to make your program work:

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
   
int main()
{
     auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
     date::sys_days t { std::chrono::time_point_cast<date::days>(now) };
     date::weekday wd{t};
     std::cout << wd << '\n';
}
```

**edit:** Now let's do a bit more, and thanks @HowardHinnant for the informative comments.

#### Use more meaningful names

Replace the code for `main()` with

```
auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
date::sys_days now_in_days { std::chrono::time_point_cast<date::days>(now) };
date::weekday weekday {now_in_days};
std::cout << weekday << '\n';
```

#### Get the weekday as a number

You said you wanted to get the weekday as a number. Well, we can do that:

```
auto weekday_index = weekday.c_encoding();
```

the type will be `unsigned`, and the value will be in the range 0...6

#### Get the weekday in your own timezone

Your code and mine, so far, is UTC. Which is good as a default, but may give you something surprising as the weekday. We can use `zoned_time` and write:

```
auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
auto now_local = zoned_time{current_zone(), now}.get_local_time();
date::sys_days now_local_in_days { std::chrono::time_point_cast<date::days>(now_local) };
date::weekday weekday {now_local_in_days};
auto weekday_index = weekday.c_encoding();
```

#### Gotcha for dates before the epoch (1970)

This is super annoying, but `time_point_cast()` may not always do what you want! Howard says that for days before 1970 we need to use `floor()` instead:

```
date::sys_days now_local_in_days { std::chrono::floor<date::days>(now_local) };
```

#### Final program

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
   
int main()
{
    auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto now_local = zoned_time{current_zone(), now}.get_local_time();
    date::sys_days now_local_in_days { std::chrono::floor<date::days>(now_local) };
    date::weekday weekday {now_local_in_days};
    auto weekday_index = weekday.c_encoding();
    std::cout << weekday_index << '\n';
}
```

And if today is Tuesday, the resulting output should be `2`.

Comment: Further information and caveats: 1) You can convert the `weekday` `wd` to an `unsigned` in the range [0, 6] with `wd.c_encoding()`. 2) The above formulation returns the current `weekday` in UTC.  To get the current `weekday` in local time, convert `now` to `local_time` with `zoned_time{current_zone(), now}.get_local_time()`, and _then_ truncate to `days` precision and convert to `weekday`.  3)  `time_point_cast` will give you the right answer for all times past the 1970 epoch.  To ensure the correct answer for all time points, use `floor<days>` instead of `time_point_cast<days>`.

Comment: @HowardHinnant: Would you like to edit that into the answer, or shall I?

Comment: You are welcome to edit it in.  My comments were just meant to be informational.  Please feel free to use them however you want.  I've upvoted your answer regardless. :-)

Comment: Thank you @HowardHinnant for the informative comment and for `date.h` in general!

Comment: @einpoklum Looks like you forgot to convert `now_local_in_days` to a weekday (?)

Comment: @Azmisov: Looks like it slipped somewhere in the middle. Would you mind having another look?

Answer (score 2):

This would give the index of the day using date.h:

```
using namespace date;
using namespace std::chrono;
auto now = system_clock::now();
std::cout << "The current time is " << now << " UTC\n";
auto current_day = (year_month_weekday{floor<days>(now)}.weekday() - Sunday).count();
std::cout << "current_day " << current_day << "\n";
```

---

you can also use [`std::time_get::get_weekday`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/time_get/get_weekday)

```
#include <iostream>       // std::cout, std::ios
#include <sstream>        // std::istringstream
#include <ctime>          // std::tm
#include <locale>         // std::locale, std::time_get, std::use_facet

int main ()
{
  std::locale loc;        // classic "C" locale

  // get time_get facet:
  const std::time_get<char>& tmget = std::use_facet <std::time_get<char> > (loc);

  std::ios::iostate state;
  std::istringstream iss ("Friday");
  std::tm when;

  tmget.get_weekday (iss, std::time_get<char>::iter_type(), iss, state, &when);

  std::cout << "weekday: " << when.tm_wday << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

or:

```
time_t t = time(nullptr);
tm* timePtr = localtime(&t);
uint32_t y = timePtr->tm_year + 1900;
uint32_t m = timePtr->tm_mon + 1;
uint32_t d = timePtr->tm_wday;
cout<< d<<endl;
```

Comment: This works but prints out the day of the week according to the hard coded `std::istringstream iss ("Friday");`. How can I achieve a similar output without hard coding the day myself? I want to be able to return a number 0-6 according to when the program is run.

Comment: Yes, this works as expected. However, my original question requires the use of `date.h` since I could not find how to implement correctly in this library.