# How to find the current weekday with std::chrono?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-chrono

I'm just trying to print the current weekday (local time) using C++20 std::chrono.

Seems easy enough ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56507646/3554391), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52781510/3554391), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57570690/3554391)):

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  using namespace std::chrono;

  system_clock::time_point now = system_clock::now();
  // system_clock::time_point now = sys_days{June / 26d / 2023y} + 12h;

  weekday wd{floor<days>(now)};

#ifdef _WIN32
  std::cout << wd << "\n";
#else
  std::cout << wd.c_encoding() << " (Sunday = " << Sunday.c_encoding() << ")\n";
#endif

  return 0;
}
```

However, this prints `Tue` for me (it's monday). If I switch the comment to the manually-defined date (this question posted on June 26th 2023 -0400), it prints `Mon`.

1. How do I do this correctly for the current date?
2. Why is the `now()` date behaving differently than the `sys_days`/`year_month_day` one?

---

Edit: I believe this is a time-zone thing, as my *three* link suggests. I can't get this to compile with `std::chrono` though:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  using namespace std::chrono;

  auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
  auto now_local = zoned_time{current_zone(), now}.get_local_time();
  sys_days now_local_in_days{floor<days>(now_local)}; // !!! no constructor available
  weekday wd{now_local_in_days};

#ifdef _WIN32
  std::cout << wd << "\n";
#else
  std::cout << wd.c_encoding() << "\n";
#endif

  return 0;
}
```

So I guess I'm adding:

3. How do I convert a local_time to a weekday?

Comment: Hm. Something with timezones. My [three](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57570690/3554391) link mentions that. However I can't get the `sys_days` constructor to accept the `local_time` as its argument.

Comment: `now_local_in_days` needs to have type `local_days`, not `sys_days`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I figured it out.

> 1. How do I do this correctly for the current date?

This appears to work:

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  using namespace std::chrono;

  auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
  auto now_local = current_zone()->to_local(now);
  weekday wd{floor<days>(now_local)};

#ifdef _WIN32
  std::cout << wd << "\n";
#else
  std::cout << wd.c_encoding() << "\n";
#endif

  return 0;
}
```

> 2. Why is the now() date behaving differently than the sys_days/year_month_day one?

`system_clock::time_point`s are stored in UTC time.

When you call `now()` it means "now in GMT". Any casting or flooring you do from there on is all in GMT. It was late enough when I wrote this that while locally it was Monday, in GMT it was already Tuesday.

When you define a time manually, it's also in UTC, and it's accepted exactly as-is. So I gave it a calendar date of a Monday, implicitly using GMT, and it worked great.

> 3. How do I convert a local_time to a weekday?

See above. Not sure what changed between the posts I linked to (with HH's `date` library) and C++20, but my final above solution makes sense. You use the current time zone to offset the underlying `time_since_epoch()` by 4 hours, *then* whittle it down to a day/weekday.

All this is obvious in retrospect but figured I'd leave the explanation for posterity.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. The only reference to GMT/UTC you didn't use in the write-up was Zulu -- so we will throw that in for good measure `:)` Good luck with your coding.